# Creating a flag for names having atleast 1 travel through air mode (1) as Flyer

Tags: sql, hive, mapreduce, case, flags

I have following sort of data:

| Names | air mode |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 0 |
| abc | 1 |
| xyz | 0 |
| xyz | 0 |

I want to create a flag in following fashion in HIVE:

| Column A | Flyer |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 1 |
| xyz | 0 |

Can someone tell me how to write SQL query for this? I tried case when but subquery doesn't work within case when in hive.

I retrieved distinct names having air mode as 1, but there are 1000s of rows so I can't put them in case when statement directly as
case when name in(...) then 1 else 0 end as flyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Creating a flag for names having atleast 1 travel through air mode (1)
> as Flyer

You can do it using `GROUP BY` and `MAX` function

```
SELECT Names, MAX(air_mode) as Flyer
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Names;
```

Output :

| Names | Flyer |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 1 |
| xyz | 0 |